# Conversion from objective-c to Swift "->" operator

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert some code from objective-c to Swift and am having issues with the following code. Can someone provide me a Swift Example.

```
LinphoneManager *instance = [LinphoneManager instance];
instance->currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.call = call;
instance->currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.cameraIsEnabled = linphone_call_camera_enabled(call);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->` is a C declaration that tells the compiler to get a variable from a pointer. It can also be used to set values in a pointer. The Swift equivalent, if `LinphoneManager` is a `struct`, would be `instance.pointee.currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.call = call`

If used on Objective-C classes, it gets the value of an instance variable (iVar). There is no Swift equivalent: you have to change the values via properties and methods.

Answer (score 2):

`->` operator is for accessing an instance variable in objects. Expose `currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground` as a property, and use normal `instance.currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground` accessor.